# Fetch API won't posting login info to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I am trying to create a login page for a web app that pulls user data using JavaScript and then uses the Fetch API to post the data to the login PHP script that will check against the database. My fetch request returns with an error, but works with a public URL.

JS file:
if(document.querySelector('#btn-submit')) {

```
    let frmLogin = document.querySelector('form');

    //begin login process
    function loginProcess() {
        event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
        user: document.getElementById('user').value,
        pass: document.getElementById('pass').value,
    }

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    fetch('*url*', options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res));
    }
}
```

The error I keep receiving is: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" for my console.log(res). The output should be the input, which does print out when I use this URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

but not when I use my site's URL (not included from privacy purposes)

Comment: if you visit your site url, do you get a valid json output?

Comment: _“I'm sure I'm using the correct URL”_ - that may be, but that URL seems to return something else than you expect. So start by checking what the response actually was, by inspecting the request in the network panel of your browser dev tools. _“the login PHP script that will check against the database”_ - show us how that PHP script is trying to access the data that you POSTed to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your posting work, but your answer from your server doesn't seem to be json, try this for your final fetch:

```js
    fetch('*url*', options)
    .then(res => res.text()) // use text instead of json
    .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: when I use res.text() it just outputs my html and js file. Have absolutely no clue why.

Comment: Ok so that's your server response, it's not JSON, maybe it's your 404 page because your url is not correct ?

Anyway, not a `fetch` problem here !

Comment: I'm sure I'm using the correct URL, so do you know why that would be the issue? Or what maybe could be causing the issue?

Comment: CORS errors most probably. You usually get the `unexpected character at line 1 column 1`  message when there's some error involved.

Comment: It comes from the http response your PHP server send. Add logs to your server, check the network tab on your navigator inspector to find what happen

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I don't think it's `CORS` since she can read the content of the answer, it would fail to do `.text()` i believe if it was `CORS`